# Check for type of file system in an MSI package

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, ntfs, fat32

In my MSI package I need to set user rights to a directory using cacls.exe. It works fine in an NTFS environment but fails when run on a Fat32 file system. Is there a method to determine the type of file system of the drive the software is installed to?

I'm using WiX 3 to create my MSI package but any hint pointing to the MSI database would help as well.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom action preferably a dll, however a vbscript or bat file will work. in the custom action you can call the wmi root\cimv2\Win32_LogicalDisk\FileSystem property which returns the file system type. then your CA can return the file system type as a installer property.

Comment: I feared that I had to write a custom action. Thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: Careful with vbscript custom actions, they assume that the scripting host will be available.  I've learned the hard way this isn't always the case.  I would fire up the c compiler and do something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379283%28v=VS.85%29.aspx